# Microsoft EntityFramework Core CLI install - nuget exception

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nuget, entity-framework-core-3.1

I am trying to install dotnet-ef globally on macos 10.15.6
dotnet tool install -g dotnet --version 3.1.6
I am getting nuget exception

```
"/var/folders/gt/9l4q1djd12d__wt0cxkqyrc80000gn/T/bw0oop0h.aau/restore.csproj" (Restore target) (1) ->
                   (Restore target) -> 
                     /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.302/NuGet.targets(128,5): error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. [/var/folders/gt/9l4q1djd12d__wt0cxkqyrc80000gn/T/bw0oop0h.aau/restore.csproj]
```

The exception is happening here:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                        at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3(SourceRepository source, DateTime utcNow, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)
```

and here is a screenshot for the entire stack
[image]

I spent 3 days with this. I would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: this error means that you have null some where

Comment: @Exc yup and it's something in a dotnet sdk/runtime libraries that I am unable to solve

Comment: Post your `~/.config/NuGet/NuGet.Config`, it might provide more information about this issue, also try clearing your nuget cache by running `nuget locals all -c`

Comment: Thanks @MuhannadFakhouri. I wished I knew before. I solved the problem after intensive SDK/Runtime uninstalling process combining dotnet uninstall tool and manual removing for folders and install everything again.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem after intensive SDK/Runtime uninstalling process combining dotnet uninstall tool and manual chasing and removing for folders and install everything all over again. Uninstalling tool doesn't remove cache folders which is a huge problem considering that the problem by large affected by caching in my opinion.
I seached on mac on everything with
dotnet
nuget
entityframework
and removed it manually case the tool don't really remove everything. Depending on the uninstall tool alone didn't help me.